# Is it possible to make the NFS server and client work in single threaded mode?

Tags: nfs

Do we have any configuration file, so that it might be possible to make the NFS server and the client to work in single threaded mode ?

Comment: Why? What problem do you want so solve with this?

Comment: @SvW A fuse filesystem related issue wish to debug

Comment: if you talk about linux, then client is single threaded by design, and numer of server threads steered by /proc/fs/nfsd/threads file.